# qcc pareto.chart: bars are squashed - how to adjust the y axis?

Tags: r, charts, qcc

I've produced a pareto.chart using the QCC package in R.  In the default plot, the Y axis is scaled too large & for that reason the bars are too small.  Most of the plot is wasted to empty white space.  I assume this is a result of the long tail (right-skew) in the data ?

How is it possible to re-scale the Y-Axis so that the bars of the chart will be taller and more prominent (and differences between the bars more visible) ?

This is my first question and I can't post images yet.  Please follow the link to an illustration of the problem:

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8bwhmoxmwl1aic/pareto-axis.png

Thanks!
Keith

Answer (score 0):

If you type `help(pareto.chart)` you will see there is an option `ylim` to specify the limits if the y-axis. If you provide some sample data I could try it out.

Otherwise, try including in your function call

`pareto.chart(..., ylim=c(0,10000))`

and see if that rescales your y-axis.